# Android: Recycler view item fast clicking it crash the application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have search a lot what I did is created a list of items simple number and having check box Which is checked and unchecked, So when I tap fast fast on list it crash
and generate **ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception**

So I don't know what is I am doing wrong

here is my code

adapter class

```
  class SingleListItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView mItemDate, mFontSizeCategory;
    private ImageView isChecked, isTrack, isUnChecked;
    private int fontSize = 13;
SingleListItemHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    mFontSizeCategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_font_size_category);
    mItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_view_list_header);
    isChecked = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_recycler_view_list_item_selected);
    isUnChecked = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_recycler_view_list_item_unselected);
    isTrack = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_track);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.setIsRecyclable(false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
    pos = getAdapterPosition();
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(true);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
}
```

Comment: What is the line that throw the exception?

Comment: mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(true); it throw error

Comment: Your first line of onCLick should be  pos = getAdapterPosition(); and then you can access to the objects

Comment: postion is set in my constructor of adapter it is global

Comment: Where do I put this code in onclick @Amjadkhan

Comment: Thanks @Amjad khan I m getting position in log is -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are getting -1 Position in getAdapterPosition() because when u are click fast it some time throw the -1 position

You can check this out

```
if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
//Do your setting part
}
```

**Change this code**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
    pos = getAdapterPosition();
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(true);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
}
```

**Code to**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
    pos = getAdapterPosition();
     if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(true);
        notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
pos = getAdapterPosition();
```

move above

```
mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the item before using     **pos = getAdapterPosition();**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    pos = getAdapterPosition();


    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(false);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
    mSingleItemListModels.get(pos).setSelected(true);
    notifyItemChanged(pos, mSingleItemListModels.get(pos));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `getAdapterPosition`. It's not a great idea to use it to get the index of the current displayed item. Even more bad that it may also return `-1` if you have called a adapter change (which you did twice with `notifyItemChanged`).

See the docs for it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

> Note that if you've called notifyDataSetChanged(), until the next layout pass, the return value of this method will be NO_POSITION.

The value of `NO_POSITION` is `-1`. So instead of implementing the `ClickListener` to your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` you should implement it in the `onBindViewHolder` because there you have the current index.

Use it here

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       // the position will be the correct one
       // but don't store the position in a class field 
       // since it may change during scrolling
    }
```

Comment: Up vote because this is the only answer that addresses the problem behind the issue the OP is having. The issue being the OP started with poor code design. The other answers (including the accepted one) are a quick fixes but do not eliminate the true issue.